# What is the difference between sar -B verses sar -W

Tags: linux, system-monitoring, sar

I am trying to understand why my system is running slowly. I found the sar command, but wanted to know the difference between sar -B and sar -W

I read the man page, and I understand that -B gives me the paging statistics and -W gives me the swapping statistics. What I would like to understand is the following:

What is the correlation between the two sets of statistics.

When should I be concerned about -B and when about -W? ie, what values from each command should I be concerned with?

Which statistic is more closely related to system performance

Thanks

Comment: Which version of sar are you running? (there are multiple implementations) `-W` on my Debian box shows `-W Statistics about errors for IP (version 4) traffic.`  Without knowing the particulars for your implementation it is difficult to check the man pages, and source to see exactly what statistics are being checked and reported.

Comment: sar -V gives me sysstat version 7.0.2

Comment: man sar can help you